# .msg to eml conversion issues outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, msg, eml

I am using a third party dll that converts outlook .msg mails to eml. This dll  functions as expected for majority of the emails i try to convert.  But recently, I found a mail that doesn't get encoded and decoded properly. It's a mail with some French accents and other characters (but usually all French mails till now was well converted).

As a result, the .msg converted to eml produces "?" in place of some accents and also in the message body i have some  "\f0" occurrences.

I sent the same .msg mail to the third party developer who wrote the conversion tool. He loaded the same dll and simulated the same conversion sequence i am using and he has a different result (a correctly converted document).

```
using System;
using Independentsoft.Msg;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Independentsoft.Msg.Message msgMessage = new Independentsoft.Msg.Message("c:\\test\\test.msg");

            Independentsoft.Email.Mime.Message mimeMessage = msgMessage.ConvertToMimeMessage();

            mimeMessage.Save("c:\\test\\test.eml");
        }
    }
}
```

How does one even debug this ? How is it possible that it works perfectly well in the developer's machine using the same dll and not on mine or customer ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the current locales are the same on both machines.

Also try (as a test) to run the [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) converter (see [3rd party utility to convert Outlook MSG files to EML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138803/3rd-party-utility-to-convert-outlook-msg-files-to-eml-files)).